# limiting Bash output by timestamp

Tags: linux, bash

I'm trying to write a script that will check on the number of threads being used for given processes.   I have it all written, but one of the pieces that is alluding me is setting it so that it will only output the last hour.   Is there a way to do this?

The timestamp does look like this:
2014-11-18 10:02:02

Comment: please define "last hour", it is current 11am where I am, do you mean anything that happened between 10:00 and 11:00(-1 sec), or the previous 60 minutes. Good luck

Comment: What input is your script getting? Show us the relevant pieces of the script and the relevant input data.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show [the code you have so far](http://whathaveyoutried.com).  You should include at least an outline (but preferably a [mcve]) of the code that you are having problems with, then we can try to help with the specific problem. You should also read [ask].